# android:minEms is ignored in dialog-themed activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have a relatively simple layout that contains an `EditText`. The activity itself uses the dialog theme. The dialog ends up being tiny, the edit text isn't even big enough to show the initial string.

I know that tiny dialogs are a common problem (IIRC Dianne mentioned that dialogs by default use wrap_content for the parent window), and a typical workaround is to force the dialog to be a certain size in `onCreate`. I prefer to fix this issue in the layout.

The idea was to give the EditText an `android:minEms` of 30 to give it a reasonable size (without being ridiculously huge on a tablet), but that seems to be ignored - the EditText (and dialog) is still tiny.

Side note - the dialog's height is too small too - the button at the bottom is half the size it should be.

Layout, for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:gravity="center"
    />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/file_manager"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_folder_small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="pickFile"
      />
      <EditText android:id="@+id/file"
            android:text="@string/default_file"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:minEms="30"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/file_manager"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/action"
        android:onClick="performAction"
        android:text="@string/action">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your RelativeLayout to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`.

Comment: You're a genius! My mistake was assuming that fill_parent will always end up wider/longer than wrap_content.

Comment: Glad to help. Android's layout rules are certainly weird in places, this one was far from obvious. I had to go look in the source for TextView to find out why minEms might be ignored... turned out TextView will ignore minEms if the parent is controlling how big it should be (as is the case for fill_parent). Setting the parent to wrap_content lets the child choose its own size (which is where minEms can enter the picture). Phew!

Comment: Your bounty is on the way as soon as the mandatory delay has elapsed. Thanks again!